# Uncaught Rickshaw.Graph needs a reference to an element

Tags: rickshaw

**Need some help with this  error:**

```
Uncaught Rickshaw.Graph needs a reference to an element
rickshaw.min.js:1 initialize
rickshaw.min.js:1 Rickshaw.Graph
rickshaw.min.js:1 loadChart
chart.js:23 (anonymous function)
stockDisplay.html:21 window.DoorLock.DoorLock._tryToFreeWaitList
onsenui.js:4123 window.DoorLock.DoorLock._unlock
onsenui.js:4118 unlock
onsenui.js:4100 (anonymous function)
```

**Here is the JS function:**

function loadChart() {

```
 var stockDataSeries = (function () {
     var stockDataSeries = null;
     $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'http://[host_name]/json/aa_historicalData.json',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
        stockDataSeries = JSON.stringify(data);
        },
        'error': function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
     });
     return stockDataSeries;
 })(); 

 var stockChart = new Rickshaw.Graph({
     element: document.querySelector('chart'),
     renderer: 'line',
     width: '345',

     series: [ { 
            color: 'steelblue',
            name: 'Price',  
            data: stockDataSeries        
                } ]
 });

 var x_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X( { 
     graph: stockChart 
 } );

 var y_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y( {
     graph: stockChart,
     orientation: 'left',
     tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
     element: document.getElementById('y_axis')
 } );

 var detail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({
        graph: stockChart
 });

 graph.render();
```

}

Comment: My proposal is to check the HTML code. Maybe the `chart` element does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `document.querySelector('chart')` try using `document.getElementById('chart')`. I believe your error is resulting from the querySelector returning without an element.